# loopback Warning: scope User.accessTokens targets class "AccessToken", which is not exposed via remoting

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

So, the title is a question. Trying to generate angular services from loopback app, but get this errors

`Loading LoopBack app "xxx\\server\\server.js"
Generating "lbServices" for the API endpoint "/api"
Warning: scope User.accessTokens targets class "AccessToken", which is not exposed
via remoting. The Angular code for this scope won't be generated.
Warning: scope AppUser.accessTokens targets class "AccessToken", which is not exposed
via remoting. The Angular code for this scope won't be generated.
undefined:25
  throw err;
  ^`

Not sure when it stops to work: after updating the slc or after some of my coding

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, deleting the `node_modules` and `npm cache clean` with re-installation, brings this to life.

Answer (score 1):

Change AccessToken public property to true in model-config.json

```
"AccessToken": {
"dataSource": "mongo",
"public": true }
```